# Java - How to generate a 2D Array with random ints, where the grid size is N*N (User Input)?

Tags: java, arrays, input, 2d

Total newbie to java programming and I'm playing around with some exercises I've come across.

I need to create a 2D array in Java that fills with random ints (range 1-100), with its size determined by a user-input N value (N*N).

n Value is attained through main, though I'm unsure of where to go from here!

Example goal output:

n: 4

```
2, 3, 4, 6
9, 7, 4, 7
1, 3, 5, 8
9, 3, 7, 1
```

General shape of what I have so far (be kind)

```
public generateGrid(int row,int col){
  private int row,col;
  int[][] array = new int[][];
  int n = grid_size;
  //randInt?

  return (newGrid)
  }
```

Any help or explanation is appreciated!

Comment: You need to look at Java Random class and nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Java 8 streams then you could use the following:

```
private int[][] randomArrayOfSize(int size) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[][] array = new int[size][];
    IntStream.range(0, size)
        .forEach(i -> array[i] = random.ints(size, 1, 100).toArray());
    return array;
}
```

Otherwise just iterate through rows and columns assigning a new number to each cell.